# Split a file into multiple with low disk space

Tags: rar, split

Is it possible to make split rar files from a big file in multiple sessions?
for example I have 100GB disk with a 60GB file in it, I need to make split rar files to upload them to a server which max accepted file size is 2gb, but cant because I need 120 GB.
is it possible to make 15 2gb parts, download them , then make next 15 and next and next ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ctrl+z` to suspend rar compression, then upload and delete previous created files, and then use `fg` to continue rar.

Alternatively you could create files named `myrar.part16.rar, myrar.part31.rar,...` using something like `touch myrar.part{16,31,46,61,76,91}.rar` and rar will pause at each of these asking you whether you want to overwrite.

Comment: The ctrl-z solution works,however I thought of  the alternate before but it gives me this error
https://askubuntu.com/questions/910128/possible-to-continue-interrupted-stopped-rar-split

Comment: Tried to skip part01 and get this error
`code`
# rar a -m0 -v2000000 test testfile 
    
    
    Creating archive test.rar
    
    Adding    testfile                           
    Calculating the control sum     
    
    test.part01.rar already exists. Overwrite it ?
    [Y]es, [N]o, [A]ll, n[E]ver, [R]ename, [Q]uit N
    
    Cannot rename test.rar to test.part01.rar
    No such file or directory
`code`